# Filling multiple diagonal elements of a numpy 2D array

Tags: numpy

What is the best way to fill multiple diagonal elements (but not all) of a 2 dimensional numpy array.
I know `numpy.fill_diagonal` is the recommended way to fill all the diagonal elements.

Currently I am just using a loop:

```
for i in a_list_of_indices: a_2d_array[i,i] = num
```

If the array is large and the number of diagonal elements to be filled is also large, is there a better way than above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this without looping:

```
a_2d_array[a_list_of_indices,a_list_of_indices] = num
```

Example:

```
a_2d_array = np.zeros((5,5))
a_list_of_indices = [2, 3]
```

returns:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Just for reference of others, this works the same for **n-dimensional** arrays i.e. `a_3d_array[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]] = 9` makes `a_3d_array[1, 1, 1]` and `a_3d_array[2, 2, 2]`  equals `9`